# Powershell: PSSQLITE module suddenly didn't work

Tags: powershell, sqlite

I'm on Win10+PS 7.1.
I used the PSSQLITE module v1.1.0 for one or two months, it worked perfectly. I used it even yesterday.
But today it suddenly didn't work.

```
 $db = Get-DefaultSourceDB
 $sql = "select * from users"
 $result = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $db -Query $sql
Line |
 429 |  …     $conn = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection -ArgumentL …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its
     | dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)"
```

I didn't touch anything on my PC. I uninstalled then reinstalled the pssqlite module but it didn't help.
I can see the SQLite.Interop.dll is a self-contained dll file in the PSSQLITE module. I see there's code in the module to check the OS version and load the necessary ones.
I have no clue and I've struggled on it for the whole day.
Can you please help?
BTW - this works under PS 5.1 on the same machine(same PSSQLITE version, seperate installation directory) but I have some other stuff didn't work under PS5.1

Here's my environment:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: Did you try to check, is dll exist on your filesystem or not? Try previously Add-Type -Path "/pathtodll/library.dll"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @FletcherF1 I can see a dll System.Data.SQLite.dll existed in the PSSQLITE directory and there are code to load it. Per https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q10 I believe this has included the bundle. I used the Add-Type command, then the Invoke-SqliteQuery, but got the sme error.

Comment: Add suddenly, without changing anything(at least I didnt) PS7 is working fine, while the PS5 is not functioning(due to other reason not the same error message). Maybe it's related to GPO? This is a company issued laptop something might happen but I'm not aware of...